# Take out one Third..Keep Two Third..To Total Ten

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, no-computers

There are total 36 numbers in the grid shown in the picture.

Cross out 12 of them and keep 24 of them.

Sum of the rest of the numbers should total 10 for each row and column.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer, along the X and Y axes are the sum of numbers in that row/ column to aid me in the solving process. I do not think any explanation is needed...

> [image]

Comment: Got it..good quick way